# Difference between serialize and serializeObject jquery

Tags: jquery

I search a lot but didn't find perfect difference between `serialize` and `serializeObject` method of jquery.

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: jQuery has no method named `serializeObject` in its core. If you're seeing the use of that, it's probably in a plugin and probably does the same thing as `serialize`

Comment: As far as I'm aware `serializeObject` is not a core jquery function so first you have to tell us where did you get that plugin, but in any case, don't think it's worth the comparison.

Comment: More info may be found [***here***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900587/jquery-serializeobject-is-not-a-function-only-in-firefox)

Comment: @ClaudioRedi In my project I use serializeObject method to get form data and send through ajax call. So I want to know what it exactly does and I want to push additional data to it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TVexb/), `serializeObject` is not a native jQuery Method and thus only exist if you or a previous programmer of the site inserted it.  As is mentioned in an [Q&A found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900587/jquery-serializeobject-is-not-a-function-only-in-firefox), this function was probably found when someone working on your site "`searched a way to serialize a form`" and found the following extension:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};
```

Look for `serializeObject` somewhere in your JS, but note, it's probably not needed as it <strike>appears to do the same thing as `$.fn.serialize`</strike>.

---

Upon further review, I found it's not the exact same. `serializeObject` method found at other Q&A will serialize a form's value's as an Object, while `serialize` encodes the values as a string for submission.

Please take note, ***if you want something*** like `serailizeObject` ***that is native to the jQuery Core***, then please see [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

The result will be slightly different in that `serializeArray` will make an array of objects of your form values. each Object having `{ name: "", value: "" }`

## EXAMPLE


<sup>Please see [`Developer`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) [`Tools`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) [`Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in example.</sup>

Comment: You should use `if (o.hasOwnProperty(this.name))` instead of `if (o[this.name])`. If first input out of group with the same `name` property is empty, second variant will be `false`.

Comment: @MaximPechenin : If you read the question and the answer through you'll find I didn't write that method. I simply reference it as it is the most popular form I could find online. That point was to help the OP identify where a method may be that was causing interference.

Answer (score 5):

I have done some digging here on stackoverflow on serializing form to json object and I ended up finding this method

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};
```

yet it doesn't fit on what I was working on. So I created my own plugin. If your interested you might what to check this out https://github.com/citnvillareal/serializeObject

Answer (score 3):

`$.serializeObject` is a variant of existing `$.serialize` method which, instead of encoding form elements to string, converts form elements to a valid `JSON` object which can be used in your `JavaScript` application.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is easy way !TODO--

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
        var o = {};
        this.find("[name]").each(function () {
             o[this.name] = this.value;
        });
        return o;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS for `.serialize()`, `.serializeArray()` and `.serializeObject()` for those coming here for that.

```js
let form = document.querySelector("form");
let params = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form)).toString(); //query string, e.g. value=name&username=john
//object
let obj = {};
params.split("&").map(function (q){let a = decodeURI(q).split("=");obj[a[0]] = a[1]});

//array
let arr = params.split("&").map(function (q){let a = decodeURI(q).split("="); return {name:a[0],value:a[1]}});
```

An object will look like:

```js
{
  name: "value",
  username: "john"
}
```

and the array would be

```js
[{
   name: "name",
   value: "value"
}, {
   name: "username",
   value: "john"
}]
```

Personally, I much prefer using objects as it lets you easily modify the data and it's ready to be sent to a server. On the other hand, if you send an array to the server, you will need additional server-side code to convert that into an object, or to find the right values.