# Issue with @Html.CheckBoxFor always posting false via $.Ajax Post Method in ASP.NET-MVC5 App

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ajaxq, checkboxfor

I trying to post data via jQuery Ajax function in JSON format which is working fine, howerver I have bool value and using html.checkBoxFor which is always posting false even I check it. I have update code in javaScript and force change the hidden input value accordingly if its check or not and I can see in debuging that is posting true when clicked but still receiving false on controller side. In attached screen shots you can see the post correct value but not in-correct value on controller

[image]

[image]

### Model Class Attribute

```
  [Display(Name = "Secure Entire Property")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Require Information on If You Want to Secure Entire Property")]
  public bool SecureEntireProperty { get; set; }
```

### Razor code

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model._RentingApplicationModel.SecureEntireProperty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
 <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
     @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model._RentingApplicationModel.SecureEntireProperty)*@
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model._RentingApplicationModel.SecureEntireProperty, new { @id = "SecureEntirePropertyCheck" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._RentingApplicationModel.SecureEntireProperty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### JavaScript

```
 $("#SecureEntirePropertyCheck").click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('[name="_RentingApplicationModel.SecureEntireProperty"]:hidden').val(true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('[name="_RentingApplicationModel.SecureEntireProperty"]:hidden').val(false);
    }
});
```

### Jquery Ajax Method Where I am Posting

```
 $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "application/json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ TenentJSONList: AdditionalTenentList, ApplicationModelData: $("#CreateStudentRentingApplicationForm").serializeObject() }),
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //....my rest of code
```

### AdditionalTenentList

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var AdditionalTenentList = new Array();

 $(".additionalTententUWLID").on("change", function () {

 var StudentUWLID = $(this).val();

 $(this).attr('id', StudentUWLID);

 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetStudentRecordByID", "StudentProfile")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { _GivenStudentUWLID: StudentUWLID },
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            if (data.RecordStatus == "NotAvailable")
            {
                alert("error");
            }
            else if(data.RecordStatus=="recordFound")
            {
               // alert(data.Response);

                var paraedData = JSON.parse(data.Response);

                AdditionalTenentList.push(StudentUWLID);
           ....my rest of code
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you updating the hidden input (don't do it - its supposed to post back `false`!). And the `[Required]` attribute is not really necessary - a `bool` only has 2 values and it will be either `true` or `false` and never `null`.

Comment: I haven't change the hidden input value in my initial attempt but I was always getting false, thought it can help me ...

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong here!

Comment: I'll look at in detail at bit later, but can you try `serialize()` instead of `serializeObject()`

Comment: Ok, I try in a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your posting an array of values for the `SecureEntireProperty` property and a `boolean` property cannot be bound to an array.

What you should be seeing in the 'Post' tab if the checkbox is checked is

```
....
_RentingApplicationModel.SecureEntireProperty: true
_RentingApplicationModel.SecureEntireProperty: false
....
```

and just the second one if its unchecked. The `DefaultModelBinder` reads the value of the first one (`true`) and sets the property. It ignores any subsequent values that match the same property.

I assume this is because of your use of `.serializeObject()`. That is not a native jQuery method so either your using a plugin or have written your own function (perhaps something like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488660/difference-between-serialize-and-serializeobject-jquery)?). In any case it is not generating the correct post values. Instead use the jQuery `.serialize()` function to serialize the form values. Because you also posting an additional array of value, you will need to modify your code to

```
var data = $('#CreateStudentRentingApplicationForm').serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'TenentJSONList': AdditionalTenentList }, true);

$.ajax({
    url: formURL,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "application/json",
    data: data,
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

Comment: Many thanks first of all for helping me! I have change .serializeObject() to serialize()  and I am getting null value for #CreateStudentRentingApplicationForm however I am getting value of TenentJSONList

Comment: OK, I think I know what the other issue is. Can you try just `data: JSON.stringify($("#CreateStudentRentingApplicationForm").serialize()),` and see if that binds to your model.

Comment: Or alternatively `data: $("#CreateStudentRentingApplicationForm").serialize(),` and remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`.One of those 2 options should bind your model.

Comment: Ok, I have tried following and managed to pass Model data with true value but NOW I am getting null value for  AdditionalTenentList   ............    data: JSON.stringify({ enentJSONList: AdditionalTenentList, ApplicationModelData: $("#CreateStudentRentingApplicationForm").serialize() }),

Comment: Which one of the 2 options above did you try - or did both work (and I know `AdditionalTenentList` would be null - it was just for testing :) You also need show what `AdditionalTenentList` is (the jquery code for constructing it)

Comment: Still getting null value for TenentJSONList: [AdditionalTenentList]

Comment: OK, but can you also show how you generate `AdditionalTenentList` (it affect ajax options such as `traditional: true` which may need to be set)

Comment: I have update my question above at bottom ... refer to AdditionalTenentList heading

Comment: Need a break for a while - I'll update the answer in an hour or so

Comment: @toxic, Refer edited answer. Note there is a bit cleaner way than using `+ '&' + $.param(...)` but cant remember the exact syntax but I'll check at work tomorrow (I always tend to use `FormData` now when combining form values with other values as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681))

Comment: Thanks for this great post. The `serializeObject()` function you linked was the exact one causing issues for me as well in preventing the `Html.CheckBoxFor()` from binding correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this problem, then I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654555/7039250)

I had added @Name attribute as follows

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsPresent, new { @Name = "customName"})
```

This statement overrides the name that gets generated using @Html.CheckBoxFor

If you see html code generated by @Html.CheckBoxFor, you'll see two input tags generated. 
so I just removed  @Name attribute and I was  able to submit the request using Ajax as follows:

```
if ($(this).valid()) {
   $.ajax({
     url: this.action,
     type: this.method,
     data: $(this).serialize(),
     traditional: true,
     success: function (data) {
          //.........
     }
```

Now i'm able to receive value submitted through checkbox.