# Grab Form Data as an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

My **goal** is to contruct an `object` with data of my form.

After doing some googling, people suggested me to use `serialize()`

Now, I got this from my form data

```
_method=PUT&_token=rs8iLxwoJHSCj3Cc47jaP5gp8pO5lhGghF1WeDJQ&max_down=256&max_up=256&cpe_mac=000D6766F2F6&device_mac=503275AE7A69
```

Is there a way to convert that long string into an object ?

Is there a any other way to achieve this ?

Any direction on this will mean a lot to me !

---

I've tried

```
$( "form#editRateLimitForm" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var serialize = $( this ).serialize() ; // Nothing printing out
      console.log(serialize); // _method=PUT&_token=rs8iLxwoJHSCj3Cc47jaP5gp8pO5lhGghF1WeDJQ&max_down=256&max_up=256&cpe_mac=000D6766F2F6&device_mac=503275AE7A69

    });
```

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17488875/29407

Comment: What do you want this in? a PHP object? A JavaScript one?

Comment: jQuery has a fonction for this : https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: @PierreGranger That's not exactly the same thing. That will work but only if the OP is fine with having an array of `key: value` objects instead of a single object with property names matching the form fields and values matching the form field values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between serialize and serializeObject jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488660/difference-between-serialize-and-serializeobject-jquery)

Comment: This feels like an http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Refer to this answer for Serialization Framework.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661187/form-serialize-javascript-no-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this approach many times.

```
$("form#editRateLimitForm").on("submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formObj = {},
      formData = $(this).serializeArray(),
      i;
  for (i in formData) {
      formObj [formData[i]['name']] = formData[i]['value'];
  }
  console.log(formObj); 
});
```

console.log should show

```
{_method: 'PUT', token:'rs8iLxwoJHSCj3Cc47jaP5gp8pO5lhGghF1WeDJQ', max_down: '256', 
 max_up: '256', cpe_mac: '000D6766F2F6', device_mac: '503275AE7A69'}
```

Comment: That will fail if controls have duplicate names.

Comment: @Quentin, yes it will. But if you have a <form> with duplicate control names aren't you going to have trouble anyway?

Comment: No. Just about every server side form handler will expose the data as an array. It's really useful for things like "Click each checkbox you agree with". `<select multiple>` will give you an entry for each value too.

Comment: @Quentin, Yes a `<select>` can have multiple options selected. But, if you have two `<select>` controls with the same name only one of them will show up in the array delivered to the server. The same holds true for `<input type='checkbox'...>` controls.

Comment: @DFriend — That simply isn't true. (Unless you are using PHP and haven't given it a name ending in `[]` … but PHP is weird … and even then all the data is *delivered* to the server, PHP's form parser just discards some of it)

Comment: @Quentin - I am talking about PHP and <form> submits. Test it yourself. Create a form with two inputs with the same name - e.g. 'a_field'. (They don't even have to be the same input "type")  Give them two different values. Submit the form (via POST) and var_dump($_POST) wherever it's received. There will be only one `$_POST['a_field']` in the dump. I'm not talking about arrayed inputs e.g. `<input name='something[]'>` But even then, only "successful controls" will be in the `something` array.

Comment: @DFriend — I talked about PHP in my previous comment. Look at the data being sent over the wire before it gets to PHP (you can use the Network tab in your browser's developers tools to do that). It will still all be sent even if you don't put `[]` on the end of the name. That's just a weirdness in PHP's parser.

Comment: @Quentin - Very interesting. Never noticed that duplicates were sent. Thanks. The weirdness makes sense as $_POST is an associative array with field names used as keys. Last value read overwrites any value previously set with that key.  BTW, if you really want everything sent during a submit use `$sent = file_get_contents('php://input');`