# Issue in making array in html form for JSON serialization

Tags: javascript, html

I have some form:

```
<form id="AddOrganizationForm">
<select data-val="true" data-val-required="The OrganizationRole field is required." id="Role_0_qq" name="Role[0]">
   <option value="0">Value4</option>
   <option value="1">Value1</option>
   <option value="2">Value2</option>
   <option value="3">Value3</option>
</select>
<select data-val="true" data-val-required="The OrganizationRole field is required." id="Role_0_ww" name="Role[1]">
   <option value="0">Value4</option>
   <option value="1">Value1</option>
   <option value="2">Value2</option>
   <option value="3">Value3</option>
</select>
<input name="some1" value="3" />
<input name="some2" value="5" />
</form>
```

When I use `$("#AddOrganizationForm").serializeObject()` I get the the object where Role[0] and Role[1] is just a seppareted objects not an array. How can I fix it?

Comment: in both the select  id's are same, intentional ?

Comment: Having tried to answer your question I just realised, it was not very precise. Can you give us some indication, *what* exactly you want to find in your array? The selects, all input elements? The options of the selects? Or only the texts/values of the select options and inputs?

Comment: `serializeObject()` is not a jQuery function, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900587/jquery-serializeobject-is-not-a-function-only-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `name="Role[1]"` &`name="Role[2]"` with `name="Role"`

Comment: So I have to make both `select` with the name='Role'?

Comment: I believe that won't be a problem, unless you are sending the form to a PHP (or others) page, in which case you should use `name="Role[]"`, and your values can be accessed from JS with `x['Role[]'][0/1]` instead of `x.Role[0/1]`.

Comment: Yeap. Youre way works. One more question. In my question I have made all simple, but what if I want to complete the array of objects when each have the few fields? What name should I give to the each input? Can you help me please?

Comment: It will most likely work, and you have nothing to lose to try it

Comment: What If my `Role` is an object and its content Role.Something=3, Role.More=8, Role.DoIt = 1.
<input name="Role.DoIt"><input name="Role.Something">...

Comment: I get next arrays: Role.DoIt[], Role.Something[]. But I want to get Role[].Something, Role.DoIt[]...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35117/discussion-between-maris-and-nabil-kadimi)

Answer (score 0):

use [makeArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) as in

```
var objArr=$("#AddOrganizationForm select").makeArray();
```

and, yes, remove the double `id` please ... that might cause trouble otherwise

*If* you want the values of all of the form elements in one array try `.serializeArray()` instead of `.serializeObject()`. See under [serializeArray() in the jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) for a good example of how to use it.

In your case you get this: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEWUd/)

Comment: Not even close to what I want to get.

Comment: So, what you want is to logically join the two selects, in the sense that their values should be mapped into the same array? @Nabil Kadimi seems to have understood you correctly, so it is probably just me being a bit slow on the uptake ;-) ...

Comment: I wanted to get one object of form which will have the separeted fields in this object. Because I will send this form using Ajax and the server side should map it to the object in the c#.

Comment: Thanks for letting me in on this! :-) Then my first sentence was definitely answering "something else" ;-) ... The [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEWUd/) should nevertheless contain something useful for you ...