# How to access array in PHP from Ajax call param?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making an Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "create_card.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {deck: selection, data: $(input_form).serialize()}
    });
```

Initially, I was just using the array in the call, so I had `data: $(input_form).serialize()`, and I was using this code to get the data from the input form (`card_info` is an array of the named data in the input form):

```
    for($x = 0; $x < $array_length; $x++) {
        if(isset($_GET[$card_info[$x]])){
            $arg = $_GET[$card_info[$x]];
            $sql_query .= "\"" . $arg . "\"";
            if($x != $array_length - 1) {
                $sql_query .= ", ";
            } else {
                $sql_query .= ")";
            }
        }
    }
```

But now that I added the extra parameter to the Ajax call, I can't seem to access the data in the same way anymore. I've tried `$_GET[data[$card_info[$x]]]` but this did not work.

Comment: data: $(input_form).serialize() + '&deck="selection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(input_form).serialize()` serializes data from your form to a `string`, kinda
`inputName1=inputValue1&inputName2=inputValue2&inputName3=inputValue3` and etc.

Using

```
data: {deck: selection, data: $(input_form).serialize()}
```

means that you send to your server an object with two properties `deck` and `data`. On server this object will be converted to `$_GET` array with two keys: `deck` and `data`. And `$_GET['data']` will hold a `string` with your previously serialized values.

If you use `print_r($_GET)` you will see, what I'm talking about.

So the solution is not to mix ways of sending data. Either you send a string, as @splash58 proposed:

```
// here you have a string
data: $(input_form).serialize() + '&deck=' + selection
```

Or an object:

```
// here you have an object
data: {deck: selection, field1: $("#someId").val(), field2: $("#yaId").val(), /* etc */ }
```

Where `field1`, `field2` are keys and `$("#someId").val()`, `$("#yaId").val()` are methods which are used to get some values (in this case using ids).

Comment: Came here to say the same. I set up a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/84kfnn1c/. If you check out the network panel in the dev tools you can see what parameters are sent which would help debugging. You can look into serializeArray for the form which would give an array of objects like so: https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/. I like to add something like this plugin so I can get the object in a format that is easier to work with in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900587/jquery-serializeobject-is-not-a-function-only-in-firefox. In either case, you can add the deck data to what you send.